# GitHub public link format for accessing my website

Tags: github, github-pages

I made a GitHub account. **Ex:** `github.com/username`

I made a repository (for a website) **Ex:**  `github.com/username/website`

I'm new to GitHub, and initially, I thought the public access link to the website must `http://website.github.io`, but that doesn't work! All I'm getting is `404` no matter what I try.

I've tried the following examples:

- `username.github.io`
- `username.github.io/username`
- `username.github.io/website`
- `username.github.io`
- `website.github.io/website`
- `username.github.com/website`

but nothing works.

Finally, after an hour's worth of stumbling around, I realized that I would have to change my website's name to `https://github.com/username/username` so that `http://username.github.io` will work as the public link, Which I, obviously, don't want. I want `http://website.github.io` ideally or at least `http://username.github.io/website`

So, how do I make it work? How do my visitors access my website? Is it even possible to have it my way? If not, then do I have to make a new account for every new project? Won't that just defeat the purpose of a GitHub account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, how do I make it work?

`https://username.github.io/projectname` works for me, where `username` is of course my user name and `projectname` is the name of the repository. HTTP would probably be fine, but I checked the box to require HTTPS.

> I want http://mywebsite1.github.io ideally

There's a "custom domain name" setting that purports to let you use your own domain, so you could something like `http://myproject.mywebsite1.com/`.

> or at least http://UserName.github.io/mywebsite1

If `mywebsite1` is the name of your project, you should be good to go -- that's the same format that worked for me above, except you're allowing `http` instead of just `https`.

> Am I missing something crucial due to my day-0 newness on github?

It's possible that you've missed a step, or that you've restricted access to the project. It might help to go back to basics: forget everything you think you know and just follow [their guide](https://pages.github.com).

Comment: so, what you are saying is that in -->

http://github.com/UserName/mywebsite1

http:/UserName.github.io/mywebsite1 should work. 

But unfortunately like I mentioned in my original question, it doesn't work. Only 1 link works --> UserName.github.io and that too after i change my website repo name to UserName

Comment: Yes, if your project is `github.com/UserName/mywebsite1`, then your Github Pages link should be `UserName.github.io/mywebsite1`. You do have to enable Pages in the settings for the project, of course. I assumed you'd already done that because it seems like the first thing anyone would do when they decided to try Pages out.

Comment: "enable Pages in the settings"

Oh God, i'm so sorry, i had not enabled Pages. Did it just now. But It's given me a 404 once again. May be I have to wait for a few minutes?

Comment: So, it is saying that "Your site is published at https://UserName.github.io/mywebsite1/"

and then

"Your GitHub Pages site is currently being built from the master branch."

I still am getting a 404, but i think it's just a matter of time now. Unless my day-0 newness has made me do some other silly mistake.

Comment: Then you should be good, right? If you're still getting a 404, then check the URL in your browser to make sure there are no extraneous characters. Note that the path seems to be case-sensitive, so if your repository is `MyWebsite1` then using `UserName.github.io/mywebsite1/` probably won't work -- it'd need to be `UserName.github.io/MyWebsite1/`.

Comment: Okay last follow up.
My website is up and running. Accessible via the link mentioned above by @caleb.
Thanks a lot, sir. I have accepted your answer. Although I do seem to be having an issue mentioning you using '@'

Comment: You don't need to mention me with @ since you're responding to my answer and I'll get a notification whenever anyone comments here. If you wanted to mention someone else, that's when you'd need the @ mention in order for them to get a notification.

Comment: aah, alright, now i get it. Day-0 new in stackoverflow comment section, as well. Thanks for your help, again.

Answer (score 0):

To create a website using [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com) you need to create an `index.html` file into any repository (No matter what name your repository is).

Then you need to **publish** your repository to be able to have your website.

1. First, go to your repository
2. Then go to `Settings` tab
3. Scroll down until you reach **GitHub Pages**
4. Then in source, you need to select your `branch`, in your case `master branch`
   [image]
5. Then click on save and you are ready to go!!

Your repository will be online at `http://username.github.io/yourRepoName`

If your repository name is `username.github.io` your website will be live at `http://username.github.io`

Also, you need to know that you can only public static websites.

Understand GitHub Pages [reading this](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/).

Comment: Creating `index.html` isn't strictly necessary. Projects typically have a `README.md`, and Pages works fine with that file.

Comment: Yes you can use Markdown using README,  the default cases are `README.md` and `index.html` but sure, you can use any `.md` or `.html` file.